# Why do JTables make TableModels non serializable when rendered?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jtable, abstracttablemodel

So recently I was working on an a tool for us here to configure certain applications. It didn't need to be anything really awesome, just a basic tool with some SQL script generation, and creating a couple of XML files. During this I created a series of JTable objects with my own implementation of the AbstractTableModel. After I had built everything, and got to the point where I was testing saving and loading using the AbstractTableModel (just written to disk using the ObjectStreamWriter) serialization failed. It took me almost all day to figure out what was going on. When I would try to serialize them I would get a NotSerializableException on java.lang.reflect.Constructor. I didn't know what this was all about because my table model only contained serializable entities, and all of the listeners I had attached were also serializable, and the parent class is also serializable. After a lot of digging, and a few helpful posts from here I discovered that when you add a TableModelListener to an AbstractTableModel implementation, another listener is added in addition to the one you added, of type javax.swing.event.TableModelListener which isn't serializable (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html for the interface, I don't know the implementation). **EDIT The Model doesn't add this non serializable listener, the JTable does.** My question is essentially, why would this object add its own nonserializable object internally, thus negating the fact that it does in fact implement Serializable? Is this something I should report as a bug?

FYI the work around I had was to simply remove all of the listeners, serialize, then re-add the listeners. When deserializing I only needed to add the one I created, and the model created the other one on its own again.

Edit
Try serializing this Model with the serializer class provided by invoking the setValueAt() method.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class BlankTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6063143451207205385L;

public BlankTableModel()
{
    this.addTableModelListener(new InnerTableModelListener());
}

@Override 
public void setValueAt(Object o, int x, int y)
{
    this.fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, x, y));
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Test Data";
}

private void save()
{   
    Serializer.SerializeObject(this);
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowindex, int colindex)
{
    return true;
}

private class InnerTableModelListener implements TableModelListener, Serializable
{

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent arg0) {
        save();         
    }

}

}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Serializer {

public static void SerializeObject(Serializable object)
{
    File out = new File("USE A VALID PATH");
    if (!out.exists())
    {
        try {
            out.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        out.delete();
        try {
            out.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos))
    {
        oos.writeObject(object);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

then try replacing the save method with this

```
private void save()
{   
    for (TableModelListener l : this.getTableModelListeners())
    {
        this.removeTableModelListener(l);
    }
    Serializer.SerializeObject(this);
    this.addTableModelListener(new InnerTableModelListener());
}
```

here is a simple gui

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class MainForm extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MainForm form = new MainForm();
    form.show();
}

public MainForm()
{
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
    BlankTableModel model = new BlankTableModel();
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    this.getContentPane().add(table);
}

}
```

Comment: Are you certain of this claim ? The [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.java#AbstractTableModel) does not show this, and the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) states it is `Serializable`. Of course, when you set your model on a `JTable`, the `JTable` will add a listener (the table itself) to the model which is not `Serializable`

Comment: Yes I am certain. Try it for yourself. Create a simple form with a JTable, build it an AbstractTableModel, then serialize it with an ObjectOutputStream. Now add a listener to it (taking note of the # of listeners in its listeners collection before and after) and try to serialize it again. You will get a NotSerializableException

Comment: sounds like something wrong with the code you are not showing

Comment: I reviewed the source code in the link you provided, and two elements are added to the listeners collection each time you add a listener, but I was wrong about it being another listener. It is in fact the listener object and its type added to a new Object[]. Im positive that the listener I provided implements Serializable. Perhaps it has something to do with the way Object Streams work with respect to event listeners, and not the AbstractTableModel....

Comment: I just thought about this a bit more, and the listener I provided is an inner class of my AbstractTableModel implementation... this might have something to do with it. Ill investigate more tomorrow.

Comment: Wait... that must be it. When the object is added to the listener collection, it adds a Class<?> type to the object array, which isn't serializable. Thoughts?
-derp moment... they are serializable.

Comment: _the listener I provided is an inner class of my AbstractTableModel_ that's fishy (though not necessarily related to the problem) in itself: why would you implement a listener to the model as part of the model?

Comment: I wanted to save the model when the model was altered. the class im using to perform the serialization is static (rather it only has static methods). creating the listener and attaching it to the object is done in its constructor. It made sense to have the listener defined as an inner class.

Comment: `JTable` is both `Serializable` and a `TableModelListener` to it's own `TableModel`.

Comment: Robin was right all along, and I didn't realize it. When I tested this code above, I did so using a simple gui, building my JTable around the model, then relying on the JTable to invoke setValueAt. When I tried the above code without using a JTable, just calling the method myself, it serialized fine.

ps. Robin rules.

Comment: @trashgod you are correct. `JTable` is `Serializable` as well. I overlooked that in the javadoc, my bad

Comment: @trashgod & Robin:  if both the JTable and the Model are serializable, and they are designed to work together, whats the point of making them both non serializable by using them the way they are supposed to be used?

Comment: @Robin: I've answered below; I'd welcome your critical appraisal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTable`, a `TableModelListener` to it's own `TableModel`,  is `Serializable`. Your custom `TableModel` is `Serializable`. Adding an additional `TableModelListener` that is also `Serializable` should make no difference, as shown below. Some suggestions:

- Verify that the data structure contained in your `TableModel` is itself `Serializable`. To the extent that this represents a [bug](https://www.java.net//node/650172), it may be possible to serialize just the model's internal data structure. For example,

  ```
  System.out.println(copyObject(data));
  ```
- Critically examine you choice to use serialization in this context; see also [*Effective Java: Chapter 11. Serialization*](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780137150021?portal=informit).

Addendum: I updated the example to instantiate `JTable`, clone the table using serialization, update the copy and display both.

Screen:

[image: iamge]

Console:

```
New data
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/* @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19300995/230513 */
public class SerializationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTable table = new JTable(new BlankTableModel());
                JTable copy = copyObject(table);
                copy.setValueAt("New data", 0, 0);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("SerializationTest");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
                f.add(table, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                f.add(copy, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    private static class BlankTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3141592653589793L;
        private String data = "Test data";

        public BlankTableModel() {
            this.addTableModelListener(new InnerTableModelListener());
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object o, int row, int col) {
            data = o.toString();
            this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data;
        }

        private void save() {
            BlankTableModel model = copyObject(this);
            System.out.println(model.getValueAt(0, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return true;
        }

        private class InnerTableModelListener implements TableModelListener, Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 2718281828459045L;

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                save();
            }
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Serializable> T copyObject(final T source) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(source);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
            final T copy = (T) ois.readObject();
            return copy;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Error copying: " + source);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trashgod, if you use the code I supplied above, **and put that AbstractTableModel implementation in a JTable**, you wont be able to serialize it, specifically while using an ObjectOutputStream over a FileOutputStream. I know that the title needs to be change on the question, but it is essentially the same question. Why does the JTable object make its model non serializable, if both of them allow for serialization by themselves? I tested my code above in two ways. Once using with adding the model to a JTable (serialization fails) and once not using a JTable (Serialization succeeds).

Comment: Also just realized that you are using a JTable, the only real difference between your code and mine (when I was using a table) is that I actually rendered the table on a form.

Comment: I added `JTable copy = copyObject(table)` to `main()` without error. I'm nonplussed.

Comment: I really appreciate your help so far, but am puzzled as to why you aren't getting the exception. Please try using the code I provided above, with the new edit for a simple UI. Load the app, and modify data in any field on the table that's rendered.

Comment: I've updated the example to show the original and copy. Are you getting a different result?

Comment: I used the code you provided. Loads up nicely, but try editing a field through the UI.

Comment: I also notice that you get an assertion exception with your in memory serialization. with my serialization logic (to disk) you get a 
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.reflect.Constructor
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) ........

Comment: This code looks OK. I cannot immediately spot any relevant differences between this code and the code in the question

Comment: I see `NotSerializableException` too. In a similar problem examined [here](https://www.java.net//node/650172), one suggestion was to serialize the model's internal data structure.

Comment: From the thread in your link I can see that this has been accepted as a bug. Im going to go ahead and accept this answer, because I already have a work around, and was really just wondering if I should submit this as a bug or not. Thanks Robin and trashgod for your input.