# Insert JTable data into database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I am facing a problem with `JTable` when inserting `JTable` values into the database. For example I have three columns, and user enters the corresponding data into three columns, `JTable` has several rows and I have one submit button at bottom of the table. After filling the data into all the rows, when the user press the submit button, the data is inserted into the database. This works fine without any problems.

Now consider user enters only 10 rows and he didn't click the submit button, because of some power failure the system shutdown suddenly. Now I want to store these 10 rows in a collection and when the application is started again I want to insert these 10 rows values automatically into the database. Please consider that user information is very critical information. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: tons post here about ...

Comment: *"bcs of some power failure"* - A collection isn't going to save you here :P.  You could use a "temporary"/"shadow" table in the database or a single user database with no constraints.  So each time the `JTable` is updated, you also "shadow" those changes to the "temp" table.  It becomes messy as you need to ensure that the data which is inserted into the "main" database is removed from the "shadow", otherwise you're going to run into some pretty interesting issues

Comment: Serialization could help you. [jtables Serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282817/why-do-jtables-make-tablemodels-non-serializable-when-rendered)

Answer (score 0):

Rightly said by @madprogrammer you have to take help of temp tables,
just add a ***action listener*** to ***jtable***after insertion of row data it will transfer your data into temp tables.

-- `after click on submit button, there should be check that if data is present in temp tables, first insert these data into main table.and truncate or delete data from temp tables.`

here collection will not work for you.
Hope it may help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, its helpful me a lot.